# How to get a menu item depending on its ID (Wordpress walker)

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a custom walker for the `nav_menu`. I want to check when the `$depth == 1` if its parent has a certain value. I'm getting the ID of the parent using `$item->menu_item_parent;`.

My question: is there any function like `$parent = get_item_menu_parent($item->menu_item_parent);`?

Answer (score 0):

What about `get_post_ancestors()` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors)):

```
$ancestors = get_post_ancestors( $item->ID );
$daddy = $ancestors[0];
$grandpa = $ancestors[1];
```

Comment: Use `print_r($ancestors);` to see what `$ancestors` contains

Comment: Already done all what I got is `Array()` even if it has parents